# Bluemix containers LOG_LOCATIONS with patterns

Tags: tomcat, logging, containers, ibm-cloud

I am using containers in IBM Bluemix and using the LOG_LOCATIONS environment variable to specify my application log location which is deployed on tomcat.

Now the problem is that tomcat also produces its own logs with names like "catalina.2016-12-19.log", "localhost_access_log.2016-12-16.txt", "localhost.2016-12-15.log" etc. i.e. log names with dates (even current date logs are named like this). I want to add all current date logs to bluemix kibana using environment variable but that would need some kind of pattern or something.. How can it be done?

I have already tried having "*" in the path but it didn't work. I tried the following env var -

```
LOG_LOCATIONS=/usr/local/tomcat/logs/*.log
```

Comment: Why not changing the Log Files Configuration of Tomcat in Docker image to fixed files names? Since it's a Container you don't need the file date mechanism to retain multiple versions of the log files. The crawler is using fixed filenames no patterns so I would change the Tomcat logging described here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html